# Passing an "adress" as a function argument - Python 3

Tags: c, python-3.x, function, pointers

I'm trying to use a C file that contains two functions, and one of them is a function that takes as argument the address of a variable (in C denoted by "&" and changes the value of that variable (at least this is what I believe)). Here are the functions (They are kind of complicated to understand)

```
#define LEN 255
static float u[97],c,cd,cm;
static int i97,j97,ileft;

ranmar1_(ran)
float *ran;
   {
   register float uni, cint;
   register float* listptr;
   register int ivec,i97int,j97int;
   static float rvec[LEN];
   if (ileft < 0)
      {
      i97int = i97;
      j97int = j97;
      cint = c;
      for (ivec = 0; ivec <= LEN; ivec++)
         {
         uni = u[i97int] - u[j97int];
         if (uni < 0) uni++;
         u[i97int--] = uni;
         if (i97int < 0) i97int = 96;
         j97int--;
         if (j97int < 0) j97int = 96;
         cint -= cd;
         if (cint < 0.) cint += cm;
         uni -= cint;
         if ( uni < 0.) uni++;
         rvec[ivec] = uni;
         }
      ileft = LEN;
      c = cint;
      j97 = j97int;
      i97 = i97int;
      }
   *ran = rvec[ileft--];
   }
/*****************************************************************/
rmarin_(ij,kl)
int ij,kl;
   {
   int i,j,k,l,m,ii,jj;
   float s,t;
    printf("%d\n",ij);
    printf("%d\n",kl);
    printf("*******************\n");
   i = ((ij/177) % 177) + 2;
   j = (ij % 177) + 2;
   k = ((kl/169) % 178) + 1;
   l = kl  % 169;
   for (ii = 0; ii <= 96; ii++)
      {
      s = 0;
      t = .5;
      for (jj = 1; jj <= 24; jj++)
         {
         m = (( (i*j) % 179)*k) % 179;
         i = j;
         j = k;
         k = m;
         l = (53*l +1) % 169;
         if (( (l*m) % 64) >= 32) s = s + t;
         t = 0.5 * t;
         }
      u[ii] = s;
      }
   c = 362436./16777216.;
   cd = 7654321./16777216.;
   cm = 16777213./16777216.;
   i97 = 96;
   j97 = 32;
   ileft=(-1);
   }
/*****************************************************************/
```

An example of the usage in C would be:

```
int seed1;
int seed2;

rmarin_(seed1,seed2);
float rand;
ranmar1_(&rand);
```

And so the value of the variable "rand" would be some pseudo-random value between 0 and 1.
I'm trying to use these functions in Python but there is a problem. I'm using `id(x)` as `&x` because it's the only thing I found to be at least relate. Here is my code:

```
from ctypes import *

ext = CDLL('./ranmar.so')

seed1 = 11
seed2 = 20
x = 2
ext.rmarin_(seed1,seed2)

ext.ranmar1_(id(x))

print(x)
```

Notice that I am first using the C file to create a .so file, and then use it in Python3. The problem is that the value of x remains unchanged. How can I make the value of x change to a pseudorandom number between 0 and 1?

Comment: Where did you find that C code? It looks ancient with those pre-ANSI standard function headers. As well as undechipherable.

Comment: Do you have to use this code? You might change it so that it returns a value instead changing via pointer parameter.

Comment: My professor gave me, and told me to use it in python. That code was produced by Byron Roe, University of Michigan, in 1989. Quite old, yes.

As for change it, to be honest i don't quite understand what is going on there. I tought that perhaps it would be possible to find a good solution in python, without have the C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting aside the strange nature of the C code, `id(x)` in Python is not an address. It's an identifier that is unique to a given object, but other than that the Python runtime can make it whatever it wants to. It's entirely possible that some implementation of Python could choose IDs from the  negative integers (which are clearly not valid addresses).

The standard implementation, CPython, does use an object's address as its ID. But even then, you can't pass that address to a ctypes function that expects a pointer and expect it to work, because the address used to make the ID probably doesn't even point to the value. More likely, it's the address of the Python "wrapper" object. For example, when you write

```
x = 2
```

in Python, what happens behind the scenes is somewhat along these lines:

```
// earlier in the code
struct PyInteger {
    unsigned int reference_count;
    int value;
    // lots of other attributes
};

// ...
const PyInteger* value = PyInteger_from_cache(2);
PySymbolTable* locals = local_symbol_table(stack_frame);
PySymbolTable_set(locals, "x", value);
```

I mean, that's not the real code, and probably not even all that similar to it - I just came up with this off the top of my head - but at least that should give you an idea that there's a lot more going on at the C level than just assigning a value to a variable. If you were to try to use `id(x)` as a pointer, given this example code, you'd wind up getting the address of the `PyInteger` object, not the address of the C `int` value it holds.

What you should be doing is using [`ctypes.byref()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference) or `ctypes.pointer()` to create the pointers which you pass to your C functions. And the objects being pointed to should be instances of e.g. `ctypes.c_int`, not Python integers. Python integers are never supposed to change, whereas `c_int` is allowed to change its value.

---

Incidentally, if you just want a random number, Python has built-in ways to do that.

Comment: I've used ctypes.byref and it worked fine. Also, i would like to thank for the explanation, i knew that there is a lot going "under the hood" when we declare a variable, but had no idea of what it was. Much clearer now.

Thanks.